# Delphi compiler bug? using "object", but with "record" it compiles

Tags: object, delphi, record

This code doesn't compile (on Delphi 7 and Delphi XE2), and gives error message "E2036 Variable required".
But if I change "object" to "record" then it compiles fine on Delphi XE2, since it has advanced records.
I wanted to write portable code between Delphi versions, and use "object" on D7 and "record" on XE2 with IFDEFs, but it looks like impossibile in this case. Am I wrong, or this is a real compiler bug?

```
type

  TD = String;

  TC = object
  public
    V: String;
    function D: TD;
  end;

  TB = object
  public
    V: String;
    function C: TC;
  end;

  TA = object
  public
    V: String;
    function B: TB;
  end;

function TC.D: TD; begin end;
function TB.C: TC; begin end;
function TA.B: TB; begin end;

procedure Test;
var
  A: TA;
  s: string;
begin
  s := A.V; // Ok
  s := A.B.V; // Ok
  s := A.B.C.V; // "E2036 Variable required", the cursor is between "C" and "."
end;
```

Thanks to everyone for the fast response. Surprisingly I found a workaround some minutes later. The "object" must have at leas one virtual method (and it's size must not be zero, so it must have a data field, but it don't have to be a managed type as "V: string" is). This ugly code compiles on Delphi 7 and also on Delphi XE2 if
HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD is defined.

```
{.$define HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}

type

  TE = String;

  TD = {$ifdef HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}record{$else}object{$endif}
  public
    V: String;
    function E: TE; {$ifndef HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}virtual;{$endif}
  end;

  TC = {$ifdef HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}record{$else}object{$endif}
  public
    V: String;
    function D: TD; {$ifndef HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}virtual;{$endif}
  end;

  TB = {$ifdef HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}record{$else}object{$endif}
  public
    V: String;
    function C: TC; {$ifndef HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}virtual;{$endif}
  end;

  TA = {$ifdef HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}record{$else}object{$endif}
  public
    V: String;
    function B: TB; {$ifndef HAS_ADVANCEDRECORD}virtual;{$endif}
  end;

function TD.E: TE; begin end;
function TC.D: TD; begin end;
function TB.C: TC; begin end;
function TA.B: TB; begin end;

procedure Test;
var
  A: TA;
  s: string;
begin
  s := A.V; //* Ok
  s := A.B.V; //* Ok
  s := A.B.C.D.E; //* Solved: "E2036 Variable required"
end;
```

Actually I wanted to play with a fluent syntax sql query builder, and advanced records have an advantage over TObject. That is, they don't require lifetime management. A natural solution is using interfaces here, but I always got trouble with them.

I guess, it better worth to improve my knowledge on interfaces...

Comment: Using ``object`` is outdated. Use ``record`` or ``class``.

Comment: If you want to write code for Delphi 7 and XE2, you might have to consider quite some other things, e.g. like the string type being ANSI in Delphi 7, but Unicode in XE2!

Comment: @DelphiCoder Delphi 7 didn't support enhanced records, so it's classes or the outdated object style which will fail whenever it is most inconvenient. (The code above should compile fine. That it doesn't means there is a bug in the compiler. But that bug is very unlikely to ever get fixed.)

Comment: @dummzeuch I feared that record with methods would not work in D7 :(

Comment: @malom can you at least upgrade from D7 to D2007?

Comment: Yeah it's a bug. This code compiles in later versions. But who cares about `object`. Give it up.

Comment: @David Heffernan: "But who cares about object" - Only who raises a TLabel as exception...thanx for your extra patience.

Comment: @malom: TLabel is not an object, it's a class (`TLabel = class`) in the source. So is an exception. In fact, all the way back to Delphi 1, even `TObject` is a class, not an object. It's defined as `TObject = class` in the VCL source as well. Can the object and move to a class - object has been deprecated since Delphi 1 was released, and is only still around for backward compatibility (that should have been abandoned 20 years ago).

Comment: Per Delphi's ["Object Types" documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Object_Types): "*Object types are supported for backward compatibility only. Their use is not recommended.*" `object` existed in Turbo Pascal before Delphi 1 introduced `class`. In all versions of Delphi, use `class` for reference types, and `record` for value types. Ignore `object` exists.

Comment: @David Heffernan: "Yeah it's a bug." - Could you please write it as an answer and I accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. You could submit a bug report, which would at least document it. However, I seriously doubt that Embarcadero will ever devote more resources to fixing it, and in any case that wouldn't help you with your older versions of Delphi.